# Problem with multiple dependency injection using Ninject

Tags: c#, .net, dependency-injection, ninject, sample

As a disclaimer I shall say that I'm still trying to wrap my head around the whole DI pattern therefore I guess it's needless to say that my code might probably have a major conceptual bug.

With that, what I'm trying to do is inject two properties on the following implementation:

```
interface ISurface
{
    string Use();
}

class Canvas : ISurface
{
    public string Use()
    {
        return "canvas";
    }
}

class Hardboard : ISurface
{
    public string Use()
    {
        return "hardboard";
    }
}

interface IMaterial
{
    string Apply(string surface);
}

class Oil : IMaterial
{
    public string Apply(string surface)
    {
        return "painted with oil on {0}";
    }
}

class Acrylic : IMaterial
{
    public string Apply(string surface)
    {
        return "painted with acrylic on {0}";
    }
}

class Artist
{
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [Inject]
    public IMaterial Material { get; set; }

    [Inject]
    public ISurface Surface { get; set; }

    public string Paint()
    {
        return Material.Apply(Surface.Use());
    }
}

class PainterModule : NinjectModule
{
    public override void Load()
    {
        Bind<ISurface>().To<Canvas>();
        Bind<IMaterial>().To<Oil>();
        Bind<Artist>().ToSelf();
    }
}
```

So when I call the method:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        try
        {
            IKernel kernel = new StandardKernel(new PainterModule());
            Artist artist = kernel.Get<Artist>();
            artist.Name = "Peter Gibbons";
            Console.WriteLine(artist.Name + artist.Paint());
        }
        catch (Exception error)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(error.Message);
            throw;
        }
        finally
        {
            Console.ReadKey(true);
        }
    }
}
```

Surprisingly for me it outputs:

```
"Peter Gibbons painted with oil on {0}"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like everything is resolving fine, but do you mean for `Oil.Apply()` to use `string.Format()`?

```
class Oil : IMaterial
{
    public string Apply(string surface)
    {
        return string.Format("painted with oil on {0}", surface);
    }
}
```

This should return "Peter Gibbons painted with oil on canvas".